# How to access content of the groups shaped by LINQ GroupBy?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have collection of *Customers*, potentially group-able by their preferences (*oranges, apples*)

```
CustomerID | Preference  | Age
    1           oranges    35
    2           apples     32
   ...            ...      ...
   100          oranges    48
```

I need kind of of summary table so can group *Customers* into new collection like this:

```
var GroupedCustomers = Customers
    .GroupBy (a => new {a.Preference, ...}) //could be grouped by more complex compound key
    .Select (a => new { CustomerPreference = a.Key.Prefence, TotalOrders = a.Count () })
```

How can I access the inner collections of each group with all original properties of their members (e.g. "Age" of each customer)? For example, I need to bind the list of "orange lovers" to a GridView and compute their average age.

The issue in the actual case is a complex compound key and hundreds of groups so I don't want to enumerate them every time from the original collection.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the *ungrouped* collection to the GridView, then you can apply the filters, keeping the View and the ViewModel [synchronized](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.enablecollectionsynchronization.aspx)

Follow the documentation example under [How to: Group, Sort, and Filter Data in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407126(v=vs.110).aspx)

### Comments

> Binding is just subcase. I want to find general approach. Let say I
>   want to proceed with some math manipulation on the many properties of
>   the group members (like age). Does you answer mean whatever I apply
>   GroupBy, all properties that weren't been included to the group key
>   are lost?

**No**, they aren't. Add the list of the grouped items to the group, for example

```
var GroupedCustomers = Customers
    .GroupBy (c=> new {a.Preference, ...}, //could be grouped by more complex compound key 
              c => c,
              (key, g)  => new {
                  CustomerPreference = key.Preference,  
                  SubItems = g.ToList(), // <= this is your inner collection
                  ...})
```

Comment: Binding is just subcase. I want to find general approach. Let say I want to proceed with some math manipulation on the many properties of the group members (like age).  Does you answer mean whatever I apply GroupBy, all properties that weren't been included to the group key are lost? I assumed that we got "collection of collections" as a result of GroupBy.

Comment: Could you please look onto this MS example? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545971.aspx
The very last one seems exactly what I need.
I can't understand how their retrieve item.FirstName, item.LastName from Items. I my case Item just does not contain these properties

Comment: The variable "GroupedCustomers" seems already contains all required data without extra code. In the MS example two nested foreach loops make the trick - first one looping through groups and second one through each member within the group.

Comment: which variable `GroupedCustomers`?? in your question you have a `Select` that destroys the grouping into an anonymous type without the details

Comment: Yes, true. I have to move `Select` from the original statement to the separate one to keep original data.

Answer (score 0):

This my own attempt.

We should limit initial statement by `GroupBy` only to keep collection unchanged:

```
var GroupedCustomers = Customers
.GroupBy (a => new {a.Preference, ...});
```

Then, the inner collections would be as simple as:

```
var GroupByIndex = GroupedCustomers[0]; //retrieve entire group by its index
var GroupdByContent = GroupedCustomers.First(i => i.Key.Preference == "oranges") //retrieve group by key
```